# Auto Fill "Missing" based on two dates values

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, formula, formulas

I have two date columns.

My requirement is:

> in the 2nd column word "Missing" should be filled if difference
>   between [Today] and [Date in 1st column] is more than two days. Also
>   user may enter some date value in 2nd column. In that case "Missing"
>   should not be filled.

I can use 1 or more columns for intermediate calculations.

Sample file can be downloaded from [Link](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bwjl0SErKySTWXM2bGlCNlZJX1U). In that, cell "B3" should be auto-filled with "Missing" but not cells "B5"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cell B1:

```
=IF((TODAY()-A1)<2,"","Missing")'
```

If the same column (B) is used also for user input, the formula will be replaced. To make user input easier, the cells could be formatted as "Hidden" (the formula will be invisible), and data validation set to "Date" to control user input.

Comment: I need a formula for column B. And when I'm writing it, i'm getting circular reference error

Comment: I changed the answer according to your feedback. However, when user simply deletes the cell contents without adding a date, this change will be accepted.

Comment: Thank you. This formula works perfect. The only problem now is user can delete the formula. You suggested something to overcome that but I didn't get it. Can you please elaborate it by updating your question? Many thanks

Comment: The solution could be user input in one column, formula in another one, which can be protected. I uploaded an example to http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/Missing_date.xls
If you use Excel 2007 and higher, user input cells could have conditional formatting to make input easier. In this case, the user cannot overwrite or delete formulae.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. Using 2 columns is the only best solution. Hey do u know how to hide/password protect formula bar? In your file I was able to view formula bar from view tab.

Comment: Mark the cells you want to protect/hide, Ctrl-1 (or menu items Format- Cells), tab Protection, tick Locked/Hidden. Selecting Hidden will hide formulae.

After that Tools- Protection - Protect Sheet ot Protect Workbook, otherwise the protection is not activated.